# Replacing infinite values in a matrix with column averages in R

Tags: r

Let I have such a such a 3x4 matrix(let say m):

```
4  inf  12   6
1  8    inf  42
5  1    3    11
```

I want to replace infinite cells with column averages. How can I do that using R?

So the resulted matrix must be:

```
4  4.5  12   6
1  8    7.5  42
5  1    3    11
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We the `colMeans` of 'm1' after replacing the 'Inf' values with `NA`, then assign those values to where the 'Inf' values by creating a logical index ('i1')

```
cm <- colMeans(replace(m1, is.infinite(m1), NA), na.rm = TRUE)
i1 <- is.infinite(m1)
m1[i1] <- cm[col(m1)][i1]
m1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    4  4.5 12.0    6
#[2,]    1  8.0  7.5   42
#[3,]    5  1.0  3.0   11
```

---

Or this can be done in a single line using `na.aggregate` from `zoo`

```
zoo::na.aggregate(replace(m1, is.infinite(m1), NA))
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(4, 1, 5, Inf, 8, 1, 12, Inf, 3, 6, 42, 11), .Dim = 3:4)
```